# Ubuntu: allow non-root user to impersonate another non-root users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, user-permissions, sudoers

What I want to do is really simple.

I have an apache CLI command that is running as www-data user.
This user cannot login. 
But it can run a command for himself.

And I need to SSH from another server and to impersonate www-data to run the command above.

What I have locally is:

su -u www-data ./run.sh

I dont want to ssh as a root or as a sudo user, I would prefer this to be secure.

Comment: can't you just give execution rights for the group of www-data to the run.sh script, i.e. `chmod g+x run.sh`, and then add the user you have in mind to that group? (with `usermod -G -a groupname username`)

Comment: Thats what I forgot... :) going to thy that...